# Page styling: alternative to using floats

Tags: html, css, css-float

Whenever I want to place elements next to each other I tend to use floats on them. like using two divs with float:left on them. 
I am wondering if that is the best strategy or there is a better alternative out there.

This is an example code

```
 <div>
  <div style="float:left">
    <p>Alphabet</p>
    <select  style="width: 200px;">
     <option>A</option>
     <option>B</option>
    </select>
    </div>
      <div style="float:left;  margin-left:20px;">
         <p>Number</p><input type="text" value="123" />
      </div>
 </div>
```

What else can I improve in the above code. Is that `<p>` really necessary or should I use some other tag.

[A Live Example](http://jsfiddle.net/nkvP6/1/)

Answer (score 5):

An alternative could be the use of `display:inline-block;` and the use of labels like in [this](http://jsfiddle.net/nkvP6/9/) example.

Labels are great for devices with limited display capabilities, expecially handheld, since clicking on them will activate the specified field. You should always use them.

Anyway, I don't see the point in not using floats. If you know how to use them correctly, they are great and are compatible across all browsers.

Answer (score 1):

Use for example `style="display:inline-block"`

And about your second question:

```
<div style="display:inline-block">
   <label for="alphabet" style="display:block;">Alphabet</label>
   <select id="alphabet" style=" width: 200px;">
     <option>A</option>
     <option>B</option>
   </select>
</div>
```

using `label` is more semantic, and applying `display:block` to it, makes it span the whole width.

Also try not to use inline css.

Comment: is inline block supported in IE7 and later?

Comment: yes, but you might have to apply a hack: http://grasshopperpebbles.com/css/css-inline-block-ie7-hack/

Comment: inline css was an example.. yes I avoid it

Answer (score 0):

Use `float: left;`. There is no reason not to use it in this situation.

It is Very well supported and "inline-block" will give you trouble unless you hack it for older browsers.. when you could have used `float: left;` all along.

Comment: the problem with that is i have to use a clear:both after that.. anyway around it??

Comment: @Amber what is the problem that you bump into by using `clear`

Comment: if I dnt use a clear my div that follows the parent div is now rendered incorrectly