# CSS for jQuery page generation with unxepected results

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, css-float

I have this section of javascript code to populate 3 divs of icons into even rows.  Why do my first two rows line up as expected, and the third row starts lined up with .col-5?

```
function row_content(row_number) {

    var output = "";

    switch (row_number) {
        case 1:
            icon_row = Array("Arrive", "Park", "Greet", "Sleep", "Wash", "Dress", "Shade");
            break;
        case 2:
            icon_row = Array("Watch", "Cook", "Dine", "Chat", "Chill", "Grill", "View");
            break;
        case 3:
            icon_row = Array("Dream", "Blog", "Splash", "Clean", "Play", "Work", "Design");
            break;
        default:
            return;         
}

    $j.each(icon_row, function(key, value) {
        icon = icon_content(key, value);
        output = output + icon;
    });

    return output;
}

function icon_content(col, name) {
    var opener = "<div id='" + name + "' class='icon col-" + col + "'><a href='#'>";
    var image = "<img src='img/icons/" + name + ".png' //>";
    var verb = "<div id='" + name + "-text' class='icon-verb'>" + name + "</div>";
    var closer = "</a></div>";

    var output = opener + image + verb + closer;

    return output;
}

function fill_rows() {
    $j('#icon-row-1').append(row_content(1));
    $j('#icon-row-2').append(row_content(2));
    $j('#icon-row-3').append(row_content(3));
}
```

I'm using normalize.css, and the CSS to go along with it is:

```
/* Icons */

.icon {
    float: left;
    padding: 12px;
    text-align: center;
    width: 114px;
}

.icon a {
    color: #fff;
    font-size: 23px;
    text-decoration: none;
}

/* Icon Rows */

.icon-row {
    position: relative;
    margin: auto;
    height: 165px;
    width: 966px;
}
```

Follow up:  Here is the HTML to go with it.

```
<body>
    <div id="wrapper">
        <div id="header">
            <div id="nav"></div>
        </div>
        <div id="content">
            <div id="icons-wrapper">
                <div id="icon-row-1" class="icon-row"></div>
                <div id="icon-row-2" class="icon-row"></div>
                <div id="icon-row-3" class="icon-row"></div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

Comment: Can you provide the relevant HTML? The `//` in the img tag is an error, I suppose.

Comment: The class "icon-row" is in your stylesheet, but not in your code.

Comment: The // is to escape the /, for some reason a single / wasn't coming over from the javascript to the DOM.  I'm pretty sure I'm abusing floats.  I did some more digging here and found http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7227067/page-styling-alternative-to-using-floats 'display: inline-block;' is definitely the way to go with this instead of float.  I still want to know why the first 14 floats play nicely, and when it comes to that 3rd div they were offset way right lined up with the last two columns and wrapping to create a 4th row.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suspect the reason is that one of your icon images is slightly taller than the others, forcing the floats on the row beneath to be offset. Check the height of the icon in the second row at .col4

```
------------------
|   |   |   |    |
------------------
|   |   |   |    |
-----___----------
        |   |   |   |    |
        ------------------
```